# Unable to append button to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am unable to append the button to the dynamically created table.I know this is a easy question but I tried looking at the inverted commas and concatenation operator but unable to get the result.

```
$("#myTable").append("<tr id="+staticI+"><td>"+localStorage.getItem(staticI+" a")+"</td>  <td>"+localStorage.getItem(staticI+" b")+"</td><td>"+localStorage.getItem(staticI+" c")+"</td><td><button type="button">D</button>"+"</td></tr>");
```

The chrome throws up various errors like Undefined button or Unexpected Identifier.Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You are adding `type="button"`. Try `type='button'` as you are starting the string with `"` so another `"` will end it.

Answer (score 1):

The `"` wrapped on `button` is misinterpreted as `variable` which is `undefined`. You can wrap it with `'` to avoid errors.

Try like this

```
$("#myTable").append(........"</td><td><button type='button'>D</button>".......);
```

---

**EDIT:**

oops didn't notice problem is solved in comments section.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$("#myTable").append('<tr id="+staticI+"><td>'+localStorage.getItem(staticI+" a")+'</td>  <td>'+localStorage.getItem(staticI+" b")+'</td><td>'+localStorage.getItem(staticI+" c")+'</td><td><button type="button">D</button></td></tr>');
```

You have a mistake using `"<tr id="+staticI+">...` instead you can use `'<tr id="+staticI+">`

I hope this help you.